# how to access wildcards in a customer wrapper in snakemake

Tags: snakemake

I have a wrapper to submit jobs to clusters in snakemake.
one can get the job properties by

```
job_properties  = read_job_properties(sys.argv[-1])
rule = job_properties["rule"]
```

but how to access the wildcards in each rule if there are any?

Thanks!
Tommy

Comment: Could you give more code context? Have you tried displaying information about what is available in your environment, like `print(dir())` or `print(dir(rule))` or `print(dir(job_properties))`?

Comment: I checked the jobscript prepared by snakemake,
the #properties dictionary does not contain a wildcard entry, so I guess it is impossible to access wildcard object there.
it could be very useful to access it in the jobscript.

Thanks, Tommy

Comment: This has been fixed in the master branch.